# how can i trim the string in c# after each file extension name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a string of attachments like this:

> "`<a href="/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_SharePoint_Health%20Check‌​%20Assessment.docx">SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx</a><br><a href="/departments/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_Test%20Workflow.docx">Tes‌​t Workflow.docx</a><br>`" .

and i used this method :

```
AttachmentName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(AttachmentName,  @"<(.|\n)*?>", "String.Empty");
```

and i got result :

**SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docxTest Workflow.docx**

How can i split the string using c# and get the result with each file name seperately like :

```
SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx

Test Workflow.docx
```

and then show them into some control one by one.

and after that i want just the URL of the string like 
"http://srumos1/departments/Attachments/2053_3172016093545_ITPCTemplate.txt"
and 
"http://srumos1/departments/Attachments/2053_3172016093545_ITPCTemplate.txt"

how can i do that

Comment: With no delimiter between the filenames and no consistent length of the extensions, you're going to have a difficult time accomplishing this.  How are you getting the original string, and is it possible to put a delimiter (like a comma, or something else that's not acceptable in a file name) between the file names?

Comment: If you have a list of expected extensions, it's doable; otherwise, as CoderHxr implies, it's a quagmire. If it's possible to get the vals delimied, you can use Split() and then assign them to a control using DataSource.

Comment: i got it this way AttachmentName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(AttachmentName,  @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);

Comment: i removed all of the html tags first . now i have a string like in m y question

Comment: I'm not a RegEx-kenner, but maybe replacing "string.Empty" with ";" or some such would give you the delimitation that would make this a lot easier.

Comment: ok let me try that one now

Comment: Do all your file names start with test?

Comment: You should definitely reevaluate how that list is generated.  How are you going to differentiate between between valid file extensions and files that start with the last letter of a valid file extension.  For example `doc` and `docx`.  Is `test1.docxtest2.doc`: `test1.doc` and `xtest2.doc`; or is it `test1.docx` and `test2.doc`

Comment: see that was just an example . file name could be anything like blah_blah.123.test.doc or it maybe blah.blah_123.456.pdf .

Comment: But what happens when filename is `test.anyWeirdExtensionTest`? How would you distinguish this from `test.AnyWeirdExtension` and `Test.SomeOtherExtension`?

Comment: Can you also add how the data looks before you ran AttachmentName = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(AttachmentName, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);

It would be useful to see the raw data before you took out the delimeters

Comment: sure .. <a href="/departments/ITPC/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_SharePoint_Health%20Check%20Assessment.docx">SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx</a><br><a href="/departments/ITPC/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_Test%20Workflow.docx">Test Workflow.docx</a><br> @kevchadders

Comment: when i replaced it with ',' it looks like this now : ,SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx,,,Test Workflow.docx,,

Comment: Thanks that example would be useful in your original post if you don't mind editing it

Comment: If you use the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) you will find trying to do things like this a lot easier and a lot more reliable than using Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i got it this way 
>            `AttachmentName = Regex.Replace(AttachmentName, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);`

Well there's your problem.  You *had* valid delimiter but stripped them away for some reason.  Leave the delimiters there and use `String.Split` to split them based on that delimiter.

Or replace the HTML with a delimiter instead of an empty string:

```
AttachmentName = Regex.Replace(AttachmentName, @"<(.|\n)*?>", "|");
```

And then split based off of that:

```
string[] filenames = AttachmentName.Split(new [] {'|'},
                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: @Revenant_01 I don't know - what got stripped from the HTML?

Comment: this was the original string : <a href="/departments/ITPC/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_SharePoint_Health%20Check‌​%20Assessment.docx">SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx</a><br><a href="/departments/ITPC/Attachments/2043_3162016062557_Test%20Workflow.docx">Tes‌​t Workflow.docx</a><br>      quiet beautiful huh .

Comment: and after removing tags : SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docxTest Workflow.docx

Comment: You could also replace the HTML with "|" instead of an empty string and use _that_ as a delimiter.

Comment: i used ',' and the result is this :   ,SharePoint_Health Check Assessment.docx,,,Test Workflow.docx,,

Comment: @Revenant_01 check my updated answer for an example of splitting the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for extracting file names if you do not have any other clear way to do that. Can you try the code below ?;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ExtensionExtractingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileNames = "test.docxtest2.txttest3.pdftest.test.xlxtest.docxtest2.txttest3.pdftest.test.xlxtest.docxtest2.txttest3.pdftest.test.xlxourtest.txtnewtest.pdfstackoverflow.pdf";

            //Add your extensions to regex definition
            Regex fileNameMatchRegex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\.txt|\.pdf|\.docx|\.txt|\.xlx)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matchResult = fileNameMatchRegex.Matches(fileNames);
            List<string> fileNamesList = new List<string>();
            foreach (Match item in matchResult)
            {
                fileNamesList.Add(item.Value);
            }
            fileNamesList = fileNamesList.Distinct().ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", fileNamesList));
        }
    }
}
```

And a working example is here http://ideone.com/gbopSe

PS: Please keep in mind you have to know your file name extensions or you have to predict filename extension length 3 or 4 and that will be a painful string parsing operation.

Hope this helps